# Creating a repository and commiting a file with PyGithub

Tags: python, git, google-colaboratory, pygithub

I've seen the topic of commiting using PyGithub in many other questions here, but none of them helped me, I didn't understood the solutions, I guess I'm too newbie.

I simply want to commit a file from my computer to a test github repository that I created. So far I'm testing with a Google Collab notebook.

This is my code, questions and problems are in the comments:

```
from github import Github

user = '***'
password = '***'

g = Github(user, password)
user = g.get_user()

# created a test repository
repo = user.create_repo('test')

# problem here, ask for an argument 'sha', what is this?
tree = repo.get_git_tree(???)

file = 'content/echo.py'

# since I didn't got the tree, this also goes wrong
repo.create_git_commit('test', tree, file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sha` is a 40-character checksum hash that functions as a unique identifier to the commit ID that you want to fetch (`sha` is used to identify each other Git Objects as well).

From the docs:

> Each object is uniquely identified by a binary SHA1 hash, being 20 bytes in size, or 40 bytes in hexadecimal notation.
> Git only knows 4 distinct object types being Blobs, Trees, Commits and Tags.

The head commit `sha` is accessible via:

```
headcommit      = repo.head.commit
headcommit_sha  = headcommit.hexsha
```

Or master branch commit is accessible via:

```
branch          = repo.get_branch("master")
master_commit   = branch.commit
```

You can see all your existing branches via:

```
for branch in user.repo.get_branches():
    print(f'{branch.name}')
```

You can also view the `sha` of the branch you'd like in the repository you want to fetch.

The `get_git_tree` takes the given `sha` identifier and returns a [`github.GitTree.GitTree`](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/), from the docs:

> Git tree object creates the hierarchy between files in a Git repository

You'll find a lot of more interesting information in the [docs tutorial](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#initializing-a-repository).

Code for repository creation and to commit a new file in it on Google CoLab:

```
!pip install pygithub

from github import Github

user = '****'
password = '****'

g = Github(user, password)
user = g.get_user()

repo_name = 'test'

# Check if repo non existant
if repo_name not in [r.name for r in user.get_repos()]:
    # Create repository
    user.create_repo(repo_name)

# Get repository
repo = user.get_repo(repo_name)

# File details
file_name       = 'echo.py'
file_content    = 'print("echo")'

# Create file
repo.create_file(file_name, 'commit', file_content)
```

Comment: Hi! How do I get the sha using PyGithub?

Comment: Hi @EduardoValentindosSantos, added more explanations

Comment: Hi, there is a problem with the headcommit part, my program accuses 'Repository' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: @EduardoValentindosSantos Maybe they call it `master`, added more explanations.

Comment: Unfortunately, still couldn't get the results I want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220629/discussion-between-aviv-yaniv-and-eduardo-valentin-dos-santos).